# passing self with other argument on function call python

Tags: python, python-class

I have my code below.

I want to call the "speak" function with two arguments inside the main() class.
When I call speak it says that self its not defined

I'm new to POO.

```
class main():

    def blueon(self):
        print("teste")


    def speak(self,fala):
        self.blueon
        print(fala)

    speak("testeaaaaa")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run `speak()` in wrong way.

First you have to create instance of class `m = main()` and later use `m.speak("text")`.

And you have to do with different indetation.

BTW: There is good rule to use `CamelCaseName` for classes - `class Main():` - it helps to recognize class in code, and it allows to do `main = Main()`.
More in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
# --- classes ---

class Main():

    def blueon(self):
        print("teste")

    def speak(self, fala):
        self.blueon()  # you forgot `()
        print(fala)

# --- main ---

main = Main()

main.speak("testeaaaaa")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.
Comments explain changes

```
class Main:      # Class name capitalized and no parenthesis if the class has no base classs
    def __init__(self):  # class constructor. Initialize here your variables
        pass

    # if you have a function that doesn't use self, you can declare it static
    @staticmethod          
    def blueon():     
        print("teste")

    def speak(self, fala):
        self.blueon()   # added missing parenthesis
        print(fala)

if __name__ == "__main__":  # add this so you can later import your class as a library without executing your test code
    m = Main()   # instantiate the class
    m.speak("testeaaaaa")   # call the speak method
```